# Is it possible to call a method of a controller into another controller or class in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a controller:

```
class XYZController extends ... 
{
   // Code here

   public abcAction()
   {
       // some code here

   }
   // end abcAction 
} 
// end class
```

**Is it possible to create an instance of that controller so that I would be able to call that method abcAction?**

I have tried it, but its not working after all it is class. I want to use the `abcAction` method in some other class for some manipulations.

Comment: i created an instance of that controller like 
$object = new XYZController();
$object->abcAction(); 
But it didn't work. 
I don't exactly remember the error. but it stated that it can't be reached i-e XYZController can't be reached. 
I then included it into my class where i created the instance and that time a horrible error occurred :D

Comment: I just want to use that abcAction in any of my outside class. Is it possible for me to do it?

Comment: If you need to call a controller method in another class then you are doing something very wrong. Business logic should be in the model, the controller being the arbitrator between the view and the model.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836598/131824

Comment: why dont you use a helper or a common function for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the file in which you have the class `XYZController`

```
include("yourpathtofile/XYZController.php");

$obj=new XYZController();
$obj->abcAction();
```

Comment: I am not at that system where i was working. otherwise i would also have shared the error type in detail. But i remember that time(when i included the file) it was a fatal error.

Comment: are you sure you have entered the right path and included the right file ??

Comment: yeah i am sure about the path and other details. 
Okay i will let you know about the error statement. but thankyou for your response :) It was worthy. at least a bit of my tension is released :)